# How can I modify the default email that Avaya IP Office sends with each voicemail?

Tags: email, voip, avaya, voicemail

Avaya IP Office has the ability to forward your voicemail in an audio (.WAV) file, directly to your email. The setup of that feature is pretty simple on the server side. However, the resulting email has a static Subject & Body.

**The Subject has a static message that says the following:**

> *Voicemail Message (Caller > Recipient) From:(Extension)

**The Body also has a static message. It says the following:**

> *IP Office Voicemail redirected message*

I don't know if it is the Avaya application, programmatically putting the email prompt I would sincerely LOVE to know how I can modify either of these default fields to be more specific to our business, as the message appears so generic that our staff often flags the emails as spam, with a file attachment. ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So, after talking to a representative of Avaya, their engineers have informed me that the email is sent by code in the program, itself, and it is not customizable.